# Python Dash formatting with unknown column names

Tags: python, datatable, formatting, plotly-dash

If I have a Dash table structure like below where it's creating column names from the dataframe columns names. how do I add formatting to these columns? All the examples I see have fixed column names.

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
    data=df2.to_dict('records'),
    style_data_conditional=style_data_conditional,
    )
```

I'm struggling on how to add column formatting to the columns definition above.

Comment: What kind of formatting are you trying to do? Do you know how to do it if you already know the column names?

Comment: A simple number format. I can do if the column names are static.

Comment: Will all the columns have the same number formatting? This will be more complicated if you need to change the format based on the column, and you'll probably need a loop with some various conditional checks.

Comment: All the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the formats like this:

```py
columns = [
    dict(id=i, name=i, type='numeric', format=FormatTemplate.percentage(2))
    for i in df2.columns
]
```

Taken from [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/data-formatting)